# Error 424 inside If using Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I am total beginner for Visual Basic, and was trying to put all the values of a certain columns with lots of random blank cells between them to another sheet, in another columns with no blank cells, consecutively. I used the command *FormulaR1C1*, rather than copying the value (don't know whether this is the smart approach for this).

When debugging, a message pops up saying that there´s and Error 424 when I try to move x1 one row down, in the second *Else*.

The code is as follows:

> ```
> Sub Copiar() ' ' Copiar Macro '
>
> Dim x1, y1 As Object
> Set x1 = Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(1, "C")
> Set y1 = Sheets("Hoja2").Cells(3, "D")
>
> contador = 0
>  10
> If x1 = "" Then
>     x1 = x1.Offset(1, 0)
>     contador = contador + 1
>     If contador < 20 Then
>         GoTo 10
>         Else: GoTo 20
>     End If
> Else:
>     y1.FormulaR1C1 = x1
>     x1 = x1.Offset(1, 0)
>     y1 = y1.Offset(1, 0)
>     contador = contador + 1
>     GoTo 10 End If
>
>   20
>
>  End Sub
> ```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Your variable declarations are not what you expect. You might be able to better determine your error if you declare `x1` to be of type `Object` (or, better, a `Range`) instead of a type `Variant` as you have it. (Since you don't specify a type for `x1`, it will default to variant, and NOT to the type of the last item on the line). You should also, as a matter of good practice, go to `Tools/Options` and select the option to `Require` variable declaration.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (and you should add that in anyway).

Comment: FWIW - your original problem is probably caused by saying `x1 = x1.Offset(1, 0)` (which is the equivalent of `Let x1 = x1.Offset(1, 0)`) but objects need to be `Set`, not `Let`, so you should say `Set x1 = x1.Offset(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what I wrote in my comment above, here is another method you could consider for copying the non-blank cells:

```
Option Explicit
Sub vbaCopy()
    Dim x1 As Range, y1 As Range

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set x1 = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
End With

Set y1 = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(3, "D")
y1.EntireColumn.Clear

x1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=y1

'If you have both constants and formulas, try:

'With x1
'  Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)).Copy Destination:=y1
'End With

End Sub
```

Exactly which `SpecialCells` arguments you use depends on whether you are copying formulas, constants or both.  And the results in the destination range will just be the values; formulas will not get copied as such.

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you so much for your feedback. Your code works perfectly, and from now on,  I will use the  Option Explicit in front of any of my declarations. Thanks again!